# Git: Error creating pull request: Forbidden (HTTP 403)

Tags: git, pull-request

I used to create pull-requests on my project as normally, I've been having access for a long time and nothing have changed since then.

Every time I try to create a new pull request I get the following:

```
(git: test-branch) $ hub pull-request
Error creating pull request: Forbidden (HTTP 403)
```

Is there a reason why I'm getting this? I have access to the repo, I can pull and push normally but not create pull-requests.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem - and checked the issues section in the repo - https://github.com/defunkt/hub/issues/317 - and found my answer :-)

Apparently we're not the only ones, but upgrading to the latest version of hub fixes the issue :-)

just run

`brew update && brew upgrade hub`

and you'll be all set :-)

Comment: Awesome, that worked! I was starting to feel frustrated, didn't see anything related in Google nor the documentation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Same problem here for me with hub version 1.10.4

Comment: Hey @Natim, did you try updating your hub to the latest version (1.10.6)? Just as in above comment? If you're on 1.10.6 and still have an issue, mislav of Github also suggested deleting your ~/.config/hub in the same thread as linked above.

Comment: Still the 1.10.4, I will try.

Comment: Actually I tried to upgrade to the last standalone version and I still have 1.10.4

Comment: @Natim Per comment when the version got bumped to 10.6 - https://github.com/github/hub/commit/ccdfe15a371638ec5ce0f332eef7875987d60df4 - you do want to be on that version :P. Are you on Windows or Unix? Perhaps removing your current one and reinstalling as mentioned here - https://github.com/github/hub#rake-install-from-source - would get you up to latest...

Answer (score 0):

Github changed their api and they now require an User-Agent to all calls that you make to them  (for future reference if you ever need to write github scripts and don't use something like pygithub to assist you). If you don't provide the User-Agent they send back 403's.